# Proper way to keep running a loop over an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-fullstack

```
public asmTreeSelectionDeselectionToggle() {
        const foundAllSelected = this.getAllSelectedNodes();
        for (let i = 0; i < foundAllSelected.length; i++) {
            if (foundAllSelected[i].type !== "contact") {
                var selectedScenceFiltered = foundAllSelected.filter(d => ((d.type !== 'namedSelection') && (d.type !== 'contact')));
            } else {
                var selectedScenceFiltered = foundAllSelected;
            }
            if (!!selectedScenceFiltered) {
                this.asmTreeShowState.isSelected(this.sceneNodeMap.get(selectedScenceFiltered[i].guid))
                    ? this.asmTreeShowState.select(...selectedScenceFiltered)
                    : this.asmTreeShowState.deselect(...selectedScenceFiltered);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I have. Basically, I have an array of objects containing 'nodes' with each nodes having properties. I receive all the objects whose property 'selected' is true and store them in the variable 'foundAllSelected'. I parse over the entire object using a for loop. Thereafter, I filter by discarding the one's which are of type 'namedSelection'. I thereafter use a conditional statement, wherein, if foundAllSelected[i] 'isSelected' in sceneNodeMap then to select all the filtered nodes which are all selected=true otherwise deselect all filtered nodes wherein selected=true. The thing is, when it comes to the deselecting part, it is working, however, when I try selecting them again on the UI after deselecting them, it is not working. I am wondering if something is wrong with the way I am looping through the object cause you don't go back to the foundAllSelected[i] again. I would really appreciate your help and if you provide me with the corrected code, it would be much appreciated. Just for your information, the object in question looks like this.

```
export class asmTreeNodeFlat {
    name: string;
    instanceName: string;
    guid: string;
    componentId: number;
    url: string;
    transform: any = [];
    data: any;
    level: number;
    expandable: boolean;
    type: string;
    decimation: number = 0;
    showInTreeView: boolean = true;
    expanded: boolean = false;
    selected: boolean = false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked. I pasted a screenshot of the error in the question

Comment: and what does that error mean to you?

Comment: I have done console.log(selectedScenceFiltered[i].guid) and the guids are present. It's not undefined or null so I am quite confused tbh.

Comment: I think you misunderstand that `var selectedScenceFiltered` is function scoped, not block scoped ... maybe use `let` instead of var (though, not exactly like you have it ... remove `var` from `selectedScenceFiltered` ... define `let selectedScenceFiltered` above the `if` ...